# LESS not working in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, less, wordpress-theming

How to run the CSS preprocessor (LESS) in WordPress?

I'm trying to apply LESS in my child theme. I create `variable.less` and place it in the child theme folder `css/less/variable.less` and I call this .less in my style.css like this `@import "variable.less"`

in the header (child theme)

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/wp-content/themes/themename-child/css/less/variable.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

but it's not working.

I tried this also... but no luck

```
function css_less(){
    wp_register_script('less-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/less.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('less-js');
    wp_register_style('less-css', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/less/variable.less');
        wp_enqueue_style('less-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_less');
```

style.css

```
.box-horizontal{ padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em; margin-top: -1em; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: @box-shadow; background: @bg-white; border-radius: 3px; }
.box-bg{ border: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: @box-shadow; background: #FFF; border-radius: 3px; text-align: center; }
```

Link: http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/mail-test/4830-2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a LESS-compiler installed? You need one to compile the LESS into CSS.

I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less/ most of the time, but there are a few more plugins available. After installing the plugin you can enqueue the stylesheet in your `functions.php` like this:

```
function eq_less()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('less-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.less');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'eq_less', 99);
```

Please note the extension of `style.less` is `.less` and not `.css` - the compiler will automatically recognize the extension and generate a css-file for it which is enqueued.